# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in D:\Hosting\10340930\html\checkr.php on line 27

Tags: php, html, server-side

I am working on a registration page for my website, but I keep getting a syntax error no matter what I do. If I remove the entire statement, it leaves me alone but I can't then do what I want. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$user=$pass=$mail=$name="";
$registered=true;
$user = $_GET["user"];
$file = fopen("sparkapps_files/users.dat","r+") or fopen ("sparkapps_files/users.dat","x+");
if (strlen($user)< "4") {

echo "Username too short! Must be at least 4 chars long!<br>";
$registered = false;

}

$pass = $_GET["pass"];

if (strlen($pass)<"8") {

echo "Password too short! Must be at least 8 chars long!<br>";
$registered=false;

}

$str = "";

do {

$str = fgets(substr($file , strpos(fgets($file)," ")));

} while (!feof($file) &$ $str != $user); // error right here

if ($str == $user) {

$registered = false;
echo "Input username has already been taken!<br>";

}

$mail = $_GET["mail"];
$name = $_GET["name"];

if ($registered == true) {

fwrite ($file , $user . " " . $pass . " " . $mail . " " . $name . "<br>");

echo "Welcome, " . $user . "<br>";
echo "You have been registered.<br>";
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
echo "<a href=\"http://www.sparkprogrammers.net\">Go to home page</a>";

}

if ($registered == false) {

echo "<a href=\"register.php\">Return to register page</a>";

}

?>
```

My IDE on my local computer finds no errors, but the server does. Is it me, or is it my server?

Comment: Start by changing `if (strlen($pass)<"8") {` to `if (strlen($pass)<8) {`

Comment: **&$** did you want **&&** or even **AND**

Comment: Plus this line `} while (!feof($file) &$ $str != $user); // error right here` I think you meant `&&` and not `&$` plus `while (!feof($file) &$ $str != $user){` < `{` and not `;`

Comment: This is a debugging issue.

Comment: I'd say find another IDE. Aptana showed an error on the line Gavin references

Comment: This `$str = fgets(substr($file , strpos(fgets($file)," "));` should probably read as `$str = fgets(substr($file , strpos(fgets($file)," ");`

Comment: "Is it me, or is it my server?" You, I'm afraid. Which makes this question rather off-topic for this site, as it is asking for help debug a particular piece of code rather than asking a question that could be useful to future readers.

Comment: Thank you for all of you feedback, I have solved the problem with Gavin's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra ")" here...

```
$str = fgets(substr($file , strpos(fgets($file)," ")));
                                                     ^
```

Comment: @Fred -ii- Changed what?

Comment: Reload the page, you'll see `$str = fgets(substr($file , strpos(fgets($file)," "));`

Comment: That's still 4 ( to 3  ).

Comment: @Fred -ii- That's still incorrect and doesn't match me answer.

Comment: Yes I saw `aynber's` comment. Should probably read as `$str = fgets(substr($file , strpos(fgets($file)," ");` but this is a debug issue.

Comment: "Right, said @Fred -ii-".

Comment: @Gavin Ok... got my wires crossed (as it were). I'd say your answer makes a lot of sense.